# Issues with Protected cells after duplicating the google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently working on a GAS add-on project. I have a Google sheet Template on a teamdrive and an add-on working only with this template.

The idea is that my collaborators will make a copie of the template on their drive and download the add-on on the store but I am stuck on the fact that my protected cells on my google sheet template are correctly copied but my have no more effect because my collaborators become owners of them.

Is there a way around this problem ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not possible to protect a cell from the Spreadsheet owner**.

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setwarningonlywarningonly):

> The spreadsheet owner is always able to edit protected ranges and
>   sheets.

Since they are the owners of the new Spreadsheet, it makes no sense to have some kind of limitation. Maybe you would prefer making copies and sharing them with your collaborators.

The closest solution would be adding the property [setWarningOnly](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setwarningonlywarningonly) to the Protection, so they would get a pop-up warning before being able to edit a cell.

Comment: Thank for your answer, yes that's what I did with setWarningOnly, I can't make copies, there will be mass copies